# ajax retreive object from controller in json format mvc5

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been trying to get an User object from controller to View in Json format, but I don't know the reason why the ajax call its failing.

Home Controller -

```
   [HttpGet,HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetUser(int userId)
        {
            QuizEntity qe = new QuizEntity();
            User obj = qe.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
            return obj != null ?
                Json(obj,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet): Json(null,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

View -

```
function updateUser(userId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUser","Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { userId: userId },
            traditional: true,

            success: function (content) {
                debugger;
                console.log(content);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

The call terminates in error function of ajax call with Code Staus 404 because it doesnt even reach the method in controller,
I tried removing HttpGet attribute from ActionResult method, and the method in controller was exceuted but an Erorr with code 505 is happening.

I also tried placing method : 'POST' attribute in ajax call but it didnt make a difference. I dont know what is causing these errors, if someone has been experiencing this kind of error please help me.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Load the web page in a web browser. Then `View Source`. Show us these lines **from the web browser's source** - `function updateUser(userId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUser","Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { userId: userId },`.

Comment: function updateUser(userId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetUser',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { userId: userId },
            traditional: true,
            success: function (content) {
                debugger;
                console.log(content);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }

This is copied from page source

Comment: @mjwills Yes , it is actually in Home controller

Comment: Please comment out both of `[HttpGet,HttpPost]`. How did you go calling it from Postman? What happens if you load `/Home/GetUser/4` in a web browser?

Comment: @mjwills I got an 404 Error again in Postman

Comment: Then your routing is not setup correctly. You need to look at your route registrations. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: @mjwills Okay, I will do more research on that, thanks for your help :)